# Find top 3 values in each dataframe row

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pandas-groupby

I'm trying to find the top 3 stocks that have the highest return in each month from `monthly_return` dataframe.

[image]

The result should look like this:

[image]

The data:

```
!curl -L -s -o open_price.csv https://drive.google.com/uc?id=1eClVnVMMgw5bIFJ8sMS8h4d5Msj5gyKo
!curl -L -s -o low_price.csv https://drive.google.com/uc?id=1yRafpOnVQbCGUKq5YnIfXTZisCJQ386x
!curl -L -s -o high_price.csv https://drive.google.com/uc?id=1Kpwh_EgwjpSsFXojLrPvznmyl7z9_afk
!curl -L -s -o close_price.csv https://drive.google.com/uc?id=1IF96oVlbz1wOOKrcYbT7J1P6UCxVa5XI
!curl -L -s -o adj_close_price.csv https://drive.google.com/uc?id=1CjlEcxZkzYrNbqNQHPwLlAEvciEmtTF2
!ls
```

**1. Task 1** 
Import the 5 .csv files and name the resulting DataFrames `open_price`, `low_price`, `high_price`, `close_price`, and `adj_close_price`, accordingly.

My answer:

```
open_price = pd.read_csv("open_price.csv")
low_price = pd.read_csv("low_price.csv")
high_price = pd.read_csv("high_price.csv")
close_price = pd.read_csv("close_price.csv")
adj_close_price = pd.read_csv("adj_close_price.csv")
```

**2. Task 2**
Reshape and combine the 5 DataFrames into 1 DataFrame (name it `price`) that has the following format.

[image]

```
open_price_melted = pd.melt(open_price,id_vars="Date",var_name="Symbol",value_name="Open")
high_price_melted = pd.melt(high_price,id_vars="Date",var_name="Symbol",value_name="High")
low_price_melted = pd.melt(open_price,id_vars="Date",var_name="Symbol",value_name="Low")
close_price_melted = pd.melt(close_price,id_vars="Date",var_name="Symbol",value_name="Close")
adj_close_price_melted = pd.melt(adj_close_price,id_vars="Date",var_name="Symbol",value_name="Adj Close")
melted_df = [open_price_melted,high_price_melted.loc[:,[False,False,True]],low_price_melted.loc[:,[False,False,True]],close_price_melted.loc[:,[False,False,True]],adj_close_price_melted.loc[:,[False,False,True]]]
price = pd.concat(melted_df,join="inner",axis=1)
```

**Task 3**
Next, calculate monthly stock returns for these 7 companies since May 2015 using adjusted closing price (values in column `Adj Close`). Adjusted closing price is a measurement that has taken into account dividend payments, splits and other factor which directly influence overall return.

To calculate a monthly stock return, we need to compare the adjusted closing price at the end of a month with the adjusted closing price at the start of the month. The formula for return begins by dividing the last day's price by the first day's price in a month. The number 1 is then subtracted from this result. You can keep the result in decimal format. Name the resulting `DataFrame` `monthly_return`. It should look like the following:

[image]

My answer (I haven't really finished this one also because I couldn't figure out how to 1) drop the month text and 2) remove the Symbol text

```
stock = close_price
stock["Month"] = close_price["Date"].apply(lambda x: x[0:7])

stock_1 = pd.melt(stock, id_vars=["Date","Month"], var_name="Symbol", value_name="Adj Close")

stock_1_grp = stock_1.groupby(["Month","Symbol"])

stock_2 = stock_1_grp.agg([("", lambda x: x.iloc[len(x)-1]/x.iloc[0]-1)])
stock_2_pivot = pd.pivot_table(stock_2,values="Adj Close", index="Month", columns="Symbol")
stock_2_pivot.sort_index(axis=1)
stock_2_pivot.reset_index()

monthly_return = stock_2_pivot.iloc[1:36,0:]
monthly_return.reset_index()
```

Current Dataframe Table:
[image]

**Task 4** **[MAIN QUESTION]** Based on monthly_return, find the top 3 stocks that have the highest return in each month. The result should look like the following:

[image]

Any help and suggestions on Task 3, Task 4, or any of my codes that are incorrect will be much appreciated.

Comment: can you add your data as text?

Comment: Instead of image, can you add the result of `print (monthly_return.head().to_dict())` as text in your question? maybe also share what you have tried.

Comment: I edited it and put the whole question, including my codes. Thanks for your help! @Datanovice

Comment: You can use https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.17.0/generated/pandas.DataFrame.nlargest.html for Task 4

Answer (score 1):

You gotta take out the multiIndex first, I think it should work this way:

```
monthly_return.columns = [j for i,j in monthly_return.columns]
monthly_return.reset_index(inplace=True)

    Month   AMZN    APPL    FB  GOOG    NFLX    SBUX    TSLA
0   2015-05 0.015040    0.010314    0.002532    -0.010764   0.120335    0.033207    0.109587
1   2015-06 0.007356    -0.039145   0.068253    -0.025244   0.054445    0.026810    0.075406
```

A easier way to deal with this kind of data is to pivot long, sort and take the top N, so we wrap this into a function, to prevent over-populating the environment with dataframes.. (i lost track of how many you have..):

```
def topN(data,n):
    df = data.melt(id_vars='Month')
    df = df.sort_values(by='value', ascending=False)
    df = df.groupby('Month').head(n)
    return df.sort_values(['Month','value'],ascending=[True,False])
```

Then we do it:

```
topN(monthly_return,3)

    Month   variable    value
140 2015-05 NFLX    0.120335
210 2015-05 TSLA    0.109587
175 2015-05 SBUX    0.033207
211 2015-06 TSLA    0.075406
71  2015-06 FB  0.068253
141 2015-06 NFLX    0.054445
2   2015-07 AMZN    0.225794
142 2015-07 NFLX    0.220795
107 2015-07 GOOG    0.198854
```